# Data Manipulation - Sort Index when values are Alphanumeric

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, indexing

I'm wondering how I should approach this data manipulation predicament.
What is the best method to sort an index of a multi-index in a data frame where the values of on level of the index is alphanumeric.
The values are:

`[u'0', u'1', u'10', u'11', u'2', u'2Y', u'3', u'3Y', u'4', u'4Y', u'5', u'5Y', u'6', u'7', u'8', u'9', u'9Y']`

The result I'm searching for is:

`[u'0', u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'6', u'7', u'8', u'9', u'10', u'11', u'2Y', u'3Y', u'4Y', u'5Y', u'9Y']`

The plain numeric values stand for months while the integer plus 'Y' stand for years.

Is there a way to sort the index?

Duration - is one level of the multi index, the second is sum.
Please find a sample dataset below:

```
Duration                            2          2Y         3         3Y   
customer                                                                     
Invoice A                         25.50        0.00      0.00       20.00   
Invoice B                         50.00        25.00     -10.50     0.00
Invoice C                         125.00       0.00      11.20      0.50
Invoice D                         0.00        15.00      0.00       80.10
```

Comment: Do you want to sort the 0th level or the 1st?

Comment: The 1st which is the Duration in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `natsort` package to naturally sort your columns. Here's an example:

```
import natsort as ns

c =  ['0', '1', '10', ...]
c = sorted(ns.natsorted(c), key=lambda x: not x.isdigit())

print(c)
['0',
 '1',
 '2',
 '3',
 '4',
 '5',
 '6',
 '7',
 '8',
 '9',
 '10',
 '11',
 '2Y',
 '3Y',
 '4Y',
 '5Y',
 '9Y']
```

---

For your problem, a similar approach follows with `reindex_axis` as the extra step:

```
c = df.columns.levels[1]
c = sorted(ns.natsorted(c), key=str.isdigit, reverse=True)

df = df.reindex_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns.levels[0], c]), axis=1)
```

Comment: This is the error I'm seeing with the code `c = sorted(ns.natsorted(df_with_col_arg), key=lambda x: not x.isdigit())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'isdigit'`

Comment: @OAK `c = df.columns.levels[0]` can you try this instead?

Comment: @COLDSPEED i wrote the line wrong. Corrected it now, but now this line `df = df.reindex_axis(c, axis=1)` shows `TypeError: Expected tuple, got str`. where C is of type list. Tried to convert C to a tuple but same error is returned.

Comment: @OAK Can you print `df.columns` and add the result to your question please? It would help.

Comment: `MultiIndex(levels=[[u'sum'], [u'0', u'1', u'10', u'11', u'2', u'2Y', u'3', u'3Y', u'4', u'4Y', u'5', u'5Y', u'6', u'7', u'8', u'9', u'9Y']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]],
           names=[None, u'Duration'])`

Comment: @COLDSPEED - thanks alot! it works great, terrific work!