# Data Manipulation - using data frame aggregation function

Tags: pandas, sorting, indexing, aggregate, pandas-groupby

You guys were very helpful with my question before - see link below. I was looking to sort the index which had alphanumeric values.
I have run this script which was successful today but have been receiving an error:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py:4036: FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
  return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last)
aggfunc={'sum': np.sum}, fill_value=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py", line 136, in pivot_table
    agged = grouped.agg(aggfunc)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 4036, in aggregate
    return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
```

Traces back to the pivot:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['customer'], columns=['Duration'],
                                                     aggfunc={'sum': np.sum}, 
    fill_value=0)
```

The only change that I've applied before this error was to introduce a calculation to one data column of the data frame rather then run the calculation in the SQL statement.

New calculation:

```
df['Duration'] = df['Duration']/30
```

Old group-by and aggregation:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['customer'], columns=['Duration'],
                                             aggfunc={'sum': np.sum}, fill_value=0)
c = df.columns.levels[1]
c = sorted(ns.natsorted(c), key=lambda x: not x.isdigit())
df = df.reindex_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns.levels[0], c]), axis=1)
```

New Code snippet:

```
df = df.groupby(['customer', 'Duration']).agg({'sum': np.sum})
c = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
c = sorted(ns.natsorted(c), key=lambda x: not x.isdigit())
df = df.reindex_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns.levels[0], c]), axis=1)
```

Multi-index levels with new approach:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Invoice A', u'Invoice B', u'Invoice C', u'Invoice B'], [u'0', u'1', u'10', u'11', u'2', u'2Y', u'3', u'3Y', u'4', u'4Y', u'5', u'5Y', u'6', u'7', u'8', u'9', u'9Y']], labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]], names=['customer', u'Duration'])
```

When assigning this `c = df.columns.get_level_values(1)`, I receive an error message:
`IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2`

Input sample:

```
customer              Duration             sum          
Invoice A                1                 1250
Invoice B                2                 2000
Invoice B                3                 1200
Invoice C                2                 10250
Invoice D                3                 20500
Invoice D                5                 18900
Invoice E                2Y                5000
Invoice F                1                 5000
Invoice F                1Y                12100
```

Not sure why, as both levels and names have two levels.
The end result is a data frame that is sorted by `customer` and the columns are sorted by `Duration` showing the `sum` for each `Duration`. Also, the reason why I used pivot in the previous code version was so that I keep this output format:

```
Duration                            2          2Y         3         3Y   
customer                                                                     
Invoice A                         2550        0.00      0.00       2000   
Invoice B                         5000        2500      1050       0.00
Invoice C                         12500       0.00      1120       2050
Invoice D                         0.00        1500      0.00       8010
```

Am I on the right track?

[Data Manipulation - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239950/data-manipulation-sort-index-when-values-are-alphanumeric/47240142?noredirect=1#comment81431416_47240142)

Comment: Its hard to find where the actual question is in your question. Maybe you are looking of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635626/pandas-aggregation-warning-futurewarning-using-a-dict-with-renaming-is-depreca

Comment: And you are searching for levels in columns, make sure it must be `df.index.get_level_values`

Answer (score 1):

You can use instaed `agg` function `sum()` and then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
import natsort as ns

df = df.groupby(['customer', 'Duration'])['sum'].sum().unstack()

c = sorted(ns.natsorted(df.columns), key=lambda x: not x.isdigit())
df = df.reindex(columns=c)
print (df)
Duration        1        2        3        5       1Y      2Y
customer                                                     
Invoice A  1250.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN
Invoice B     NaN   2000.0   1200.0      NaN      NaN     NaN
Invoice C     NaN  10250.0      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN
Invoice D     NaN      NaN  20500.0  18900.0      NaN     NaN
Invoice E     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  5000.0
Invoice F  5000.0      NaN      NaN      NaN  12100.0     NaN
```

Comment: jezrael - you solution looks good. I'm getting a strange error with the `df.reindex(c, axis=1)`. `File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2494, in reindex
    'argument "{0}"'.format(list(kwargs.keys())[0]))
TypeError: reindex() got an unexpected keyword argument "axis"`

Comment: Maybe last version of pandas, try `df = df.reindex(columns=c)`